# Laravel/Eloquent query efficiency: Should a separate table be used for these two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm making a Laravel short story sharing application, and I have a question about how I should structure something:

Let's say I have a table for stories, and each story is allowed to have up to 2 genres applied to it. Right now I'm storing these genres directly in each story row in columns 'genre_primary' and 'genre_secondary'. I initially did this so I didn't have to use a relation between the Story model and a Genre model. I thought it might be more efficient.

BUT! I've learned about using eager loading and the Laravel Debugbar to track queries, and am using it to greatly cut down on querying while grabbing stories' authors for the byline in the main feed (using `with('author')` in the `Story` model retrieves the author from the `User` table at the time of story retrieval, eliminating that n+1 problem of an additional author query per story displayed in the feed).

Like the author name, I also display the story's primary and secondary genres on the story's card in the feed. I'm now wondering if I should keep the genres embedded as two columns the story row, or extract a `Genre` model, relate the `Story` and `Genre` models, and eager load them like the author name?

I guess my concern is over efficiency when loading a larger timeline of recent stories or stories filtered by a genre? It seems like just selecting stories where genre_primary = 'Mystery' would be more efficient than eager loading a relation to a separate `Genre` model? Is it fine to denormalize in this case? Or am I just overthinking this...

Comment: Yes you are clearly overthinking this and there is no need at all! Just delete the question and create a model for Generes instead of having it all bunddled together

Comment: You would need 3 tables, as this is essentially a Many to Many relationship, Many Stories may have Many Genres, as for if you should do it, It depends on how Professionally you want it to be. It adds a lot of complexity and it even makes a few things easier too.  Personally I would do it, but I have made many databases when many tables ( pun intended )

Comment: As for performance, you would have to do and OR, for each Genre field, In my experience OR's are not good for performance ( in general in MySQL, I don't use laravel ), and can be replaced with UNIONS in some cases to speed things up.  I should add I typically deal with tables with 100's of thousands of records, a few even in the 10's of millions.

Comment: However, that said, based on my experience with other ORM's ( like Doctrine2 ) the simpler the schema the better.  Which is really sad, because an ORM should encourage more elaborate relationships, not punish you with performance for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're pre-optimizing.

Do whatever's simplest for you right now to see your idea through.  At your current scale (which I assume is the "prototype phase"), the difference between joining a second table or having two extra columns on a single model is negligible.

The being said, creating a many-to-many relationship in Laravel is painfully easy and the added flexibility of separating your Generes may benefit you as you're fleshing out your concept.